# Repetitive output using cout in CPP

Tags: c++, loops, std, cin, cout

I tried to read a line of string into the program, and when the string is `"q"`, the program should break, but there were some weird behaviors with my main function. Could you find it out for me?

Thanks a lot!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int distance;
    int points[1000][2] = {0};
    string input;

    cout << "Please enter the distance: ";
    cin >> distance;
    cin.clear();

    while (true) {
        cout << "Please enter the coordinates, ";
        cout << "enter \"q\" to exit: ";
        getline(cin, input);
        cin.clear();

        // Finish input
        if (input == "q")
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the output in the terminal is:

```sh
Please enter the distance: 5
Please enter the coordinates, enter "q" to exit: Please enter the coordinates, enter "q" to exit:
```

The `cout` in the `while` loop seems to have been conducted twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function doesn't do what you apparently expect it to do. It clears the streams state flags only.

What you seem to want is probably the [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) function to ignore the newline left by the first input operation:

```
cin >> distance;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');  // Skip the remainder of the line
```

Note that you should *not* call `ignore` after your [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) calls, as the `getline` function reads the newline as well.

Comment: I met compile errors like: `error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
     cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`, but when I substitute `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` with `100`, it worked. Is there still something else that I should add to my program besides the `cin.ignore()`? (e.g. `#include <>`?)

Comment: @907386253 You need to `#include <limits>` for that.